# android + custom list view

Tags: android, listview, simpleadapter

i am trying to make a custom list view and was following this post
http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html

the list view accepted the custom row.. but only displays the first item... none of the rest.. so what is the mistake? thanks in advance..

```
 public class ActionBarSearchView extends ListActivity {
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.forummainpage);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                ActionBarSearchView.this,
                list,
                R.layout.customlistrowview,
                new String[] {"Title","Tags","Date","Author"},
                new int[]{R.id.Title,R.id.Tags,R.id.Date,R.id.Author});
        populateList();
        setListAdapter(adapter);
 }
  static final ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
  private void populateList()
    {
        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
        temp.put("Tags", "android");
        temp.put("Date", "2 years");
        temp.put("Author", "xyz");
        list.add(temp);

        HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
        temp.put("Tags", "android");
        temp.put("Date", "2 years");
        temp.put("Author", "xyz");
        list.add(temp1);

        HashMap<String,String> temp2 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
        temp.put("Tags", "android");
        temp.put("Date", "2 years");
        temp.put("Author", "xyz");
        list.add(temp2);

        HashMap<String,String> temp3 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
        temp.put("Tags", "android");
        temp.put("Date", "2 years");
        temp.put("Author", "xyz");
        list.add(temp3);

        HashMap<String,String> temp4 = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
        temp.put("Tags", "android");
        temp.put("Date", "2 years");
        temp.put("Author", "xyz");
        list.add(temp4);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always add data into your `HashMap temp`. you need to add data into your different `HashMap` like

```
 HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp1.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
    temp1.put("Tags", "android");
    temp1.put("Date", "2 years");
    temp1.put("Author", "xyz");
    list.add(temp1);
```

then

```
HashMap<String,String> temp1 = new HashMap<String,String>();
    temp2.put("Title","android an Immersive Journey");
    temp2.put("Tags", "android");
    temp2.put("Date", "2 years");
    temp2.put("Author", "xyz");
    list.add(temp2);
```

and so on.